# How do I access specific items within an array that I've mapped into table rows? - React

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I'm using React.js to create a list of names on our website.  The people info is stored in as objects in an array.  I've successfully used .map to create the list in table rows, and now I would like to be able to hover over each given name (or really ) to create a popup with more information from that same object.
My problem lies in accessing the correct object again.  I'm unsure how to reference it correctly in the handleMouseEnter function.

Here's some code:

```
class PersonList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleMouseEnter = this.handleMouseEnter.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseLeave = this.handleMouseLeave.bind(this);
  }

  handleMouseEnter() {
    alert(patients[???].phone});
  }
  handleMouseLeave() {

  }

  render() {

    let list = patients.map((patients, p) =>
     <tr  onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
          key={'patient_' + p}>{patients.name}</tr>)

    return(
      <div className="list">
        <table>
          {list}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The alert function is just a placeholder.  I'm guessing that my problem actually lies in declaring something differently when I create the table with .map, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Just a meta hint: if you provide the solution to your own question. Don't edit your question but make a dedicated answer to your own question and accept it. (Yes Stackoverflow is weird like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
let list = patients.map((patient, p) =>
   <tr  onMouseEnter={()=>{this.handleMouseEnter(patient)}}
```

and:

```
handleMouseEnter(patient) {
    alert(patient.phone);
  }
```

FYI: this isn't really the most performant way of doing things, but should get you started. It's usually discouraged to use bind and arrow functions in render.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'm pretty new to React, so I'm curious to know what an alternate  (especially a more efficient) method would be to create the table, and/or reference the objects in the array later.

Comment: Look here: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36

Comment: Got it.  In that article the author simply places the function outside of the render function as a separate method of the component class.  I assume I could do something similar.  I tried typing out a rough draft here like 15 times before learning that comments only support inline code blocks.
Anyway, what I've done is created a method of the component class (createList) to create the list instead of a variable in the render function, and then called {this.createList} instead of list.  Is this a feasible workaround?

Comment: No because that would also be called in every render pass and recreate the arrow functions. To be clear that's not necessarly bad, it could just mean a performance decrease in long lists. What the author did was create a new component for the `<tr>` element and passed it a callback from the parent that get's executed from the child(the `<tr>`) when it's clicked. So there is no dynamic arrow binding going on in the render function. Alas now there is more component overhead and depth to the tree.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand - it seems like it's not the arrow function which is a method that is a problem, since he uses one called renderUser.  The problem is the arrow function _within_ that method which is called when a user triggers an event: in his case clicking, in my case hovering.
So by creating a new component, building the event listeners in the new component (as methods that themselves can be arrow function, but do not contain arrow functions), referencing that new component and passing it props from the original component I avoid the re-render problem?